# jquery click event not triggered in ons-back-button in onsenui

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui

With the latest version of Onsen v1.3.8, I couldn't write specific jquery click events for `ons-back-button` like below.

```
$(document).on('click', 'ons-back-button', function(e){
alert('clicked');
});
```

But, with the older versions like `/* onsenui - v1.2.1 - 2014-12-01 */`   jquery click events are triggered.

Using latest version `/*! onsenui - v1.3.8 - 2015-07-27 */`  (onsenui_all.js or onsenui.js), jquery click events not triggered specifically for `ons-back-button`!

`ons-button`, `ons-list` jquery click events are triggering with the latest versions.

**Edit:**

`ng-click` event also not triggered

```
<ons-back-button ng-click="onsPay()"></ons-back-button>

function onsPay()
{
 console.log("Clicked");
}
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed not working after Onsen UI 1.3.0. The reason is an `event.stopPropagation()` that is executed in `ons-navigator` to avoid other problems (https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/core/lib/navigator-page.es6#L43). Perhaps this will change in next versions. Github issue for more info here: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/865

`ons-back-button` is just triggering `myNavigator.popPage()`, so meanwhile I would suggest you to use `myNavigator.on('prepop', listener)` or `myNavigator.on('postpop', listener)`: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#events-summary

**Edit:** Two workarounds for this.

**1** - As I said before, set a listener with a callback after `postpop` (should be the same than `onTransitionEnd`:

`myNavigator.once('postpop', callback)`

You can use `on` if you want the same callback always or `once` if only once. Also check `off` to remove listeners if you don't need them anymore. For example, you can set a specific callback for pageX in its initialization with `once` that it will be "consumed" with the back button. If in pageX you can push more pages, you can just use `nav.off('postpop', callback); nav.pushPage(pageY)`.

**2** - Using only the style of back-button instead of the real component, so you can use `onclick` normally:

```
<style>
  .ons-back-button__icon {
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 1px;
  }
</style>

<ons-toolbar-button class="toolbar-button--quiet" onclick="myNavigator.popPage(options)">
  <ons-icon class="ion-ios-arrow-back ons-back-button__icon"></ons-icon>
  Back
</ons-toolbar-button>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great work! But we cannot call myNavigator.popPage(options); for ons-back-button right? It will automatically call popPage(); So, in this scenario, how can we call options to execute at the end of the pop?

Comment: And also, I need to do some specific click events for different page's ons-back-button, so, by calling prepop listener will apply for all ons-back-button right? Any workaround for this?

Comment: Yep. Check the new edit. Both solutions work for that case :)

Comment: Instead of ons-back-button, you want me to use ons-toolbar-button with the ons-back button style! Am I right?

Comment: Yes, although this is only a workaround. Currectly there is no way to modify the options in `ons-back-button`. I would recommend the first solution rather than the second, because in the latter you are not doing `event.stopPropagation()` and that was included in the core precisely to avoid some other problems. I think you can also try to manually trigger `event.stopPropagation()` after `myNavigator.popPage(options)` in the second solution.